# why do these characters belong to the first group in this JS regex match?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex to find two meaningful groups within a substring that's part of a text I'm working with.

The text and my attempt are here:
https://regex101.com/r/6Sc3aM/1

The complete regex:

```
Artikelnummer(?:(?:&&&))(.*)(?:\s*.*)\W?(?:Dokumentation&&&KKS-Nummer&&&Beschreibung&&&Seite)(&&&([^(&&&)]+)&&&([^(&&&)]+)&&&(\d+))+
```

The test string:

```
%5B"Deckblatt: Anlagendokumentation&&&Produktdaten&&&KKS-Nummer&&&Hersteller&&&Typ&&&Artikelnummer&&&MA-KF1&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF11&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF12&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF13&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF14&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF15&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF16&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF17&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF18&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF19&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF20&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF21&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF22&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF23&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF24&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF25&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF26&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF27&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF28&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF29&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF30&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF31&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF32&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF33&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF34&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF35&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF36&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF37&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF38&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF39&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF40&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&MA-KF41&&&Beckhoff&&&EK1100&&&BECK%2EEK1100&&&Dokumentation&&&KKS-Nummer&&&Beschreibung&&&Seite&&&all&&&Vorwort&&&6&&&all&&&Produktübersicht&&&7&&&all&&&Grundlagen&&&8&&&all&&&Montage und Verdrahtung&&&9&&&all&&&Inbetriebnahme%2FAnwendungshinweise&&&10&&&all&&&Fehlerbehandlung und Diagnose&&&11&&&all&&&Anhang 1&&&12&&&all&&&Anhang 2&&&13&&&all&&&Anhang 3&&&14&&&all&&&Anhang 4&&&15&&&all&&&Anhang 5&&&16&&&all&&&Anhang 6&&&17&&&all&&&Anhang 7&&&18&&&all&&&Anhang 8&&&19&&&all&&&Anhang 9&&&20&&&all&&&Anhang 10&&&21&&&all&&&Anhang 11&&&22&&&all&&&Anhang 12&&&23&&&all&&&Anhang 13&&&24&&&all&&&Anhang 14&&&25&&&all&&&Anhang 15&&&26&&&all&&&Anhang 16&&&27&&&all&&&Anhang 17&&&28&&&all&&&Anhang 18&&&29&&&all&&&Anhang 19&&&30&&&all&&&Anhang 20&&&31&&&all&&&Anhang 21&&&32&&&all&&&Anhang 22&&&33&&&all&&&Anhang 23&&&34&&&all&&&Anhang 24&&&35&&&all&&&Anhang 25&&&36&&&all&&&Anhang 26&&&37&&&all&&&Anhang 27&&&38&&&all&&&Anhang 28&&&39&&&all&&&Anhang 29&&&40&&&all&&&Anhang 30&&&41&&&all&&&Anhang 31&&&42&&&all&&&Anhang 32&&&43&&&all&&&Anhang 33&&&44&&&all&&&Anhang 34&&&45&&&all&&&Anhang 35&&&46&&&all&&&Anhang 36&&&47&&&all&&&Anhang 37&&&48&&&all&&&Anhang 38&&&49&&&all&&&Anhang 39&&&50&&&all&&&Anhang 40&&&51&&&all&&&Anhang 41&&&52&&&all&&&Anhang 42&&&53"%5D
```

The regex I wrote should get a first group, which appears after /Artikelnummer/ and before /Dokumentation&&&/ (etc), as well as a second group, which is what I'm having trouble with:

It should consist of repetitions of this pattern: `(&&&([^(&&&)]+)&&&([^(&&&)]+)&&&(\d+)+`

By my reckoning, that should capture the entire substring:

```
&&&all&&&Vorwort&&&6&&&all&&&Produktübersicht&&&7&&&all&&&Grundlagen&&&8&&&all&&&Montage und Verdrahtung&&&9&&&all&&&Inbetriebnahme%2FAnwendungshinweise&&&10&&&all&&&Fehlerbehandlung und Diagnose&&&11&&&all&&&Anhang 1&&&12&&&all&&&Anhang 2&&&13&&&all&&&Anhang 3&&&14&&&all&&&Anhang 4&&&15&&&all&&&Anhang 5&&&16&&&all&&&Anhang 6&&&17&&&all&&&Anhang 7&&&18&&&all&&&Anhang 8&&&19&&&all&&&Anhang 9&&&20&&&all&&&Anhang 10&&&21&&&all&&&Anhang 11&&&22&&&all&&&Anhang 12&&&23&&&all&&&Anhang 13&&&24&&&all&&&Anhang 14&&&25&&&all&&&Anhang 15&&&26&&&all&&&Anhang 16&&&27&&&all&&&Anhang 17&&&28&&&all&&&Anhang 18&&&29&&&all&&&Anhang 19&&&30&&&all&&&Anhang 20&&&31&&&all&&&Anhang 21&&&32&&&all&&&Anhang 22&&&33&&&all&&&Anhang 23&&&34&&&all&&&Anhang 24&&&35&&&all&&&Anhang 25&&&36&&&all&&&Anhang 26&&&37&&&all&&&Anhang 27&&&38&&&all&&&Anhang 28&&&39&&&all&&&Anhang 29&&&40&&&all&&&Anhang 30&&&41&&&all&&&Anhang 31&&&42&&&all&&&Anhang 32&&&43&&&all&&&Anhang 33&&&44&&&all&&&Anhang 34&&&45&&&all&&&Anhang 35&&&46&&&all&&&Anhang 36&&&47&&&all&&&Anhang 37&&&48&&&all&&&Anhang 38&&&49&&&all&&&Anhang 39&&&50&&&all&&&Anhang 40&&&51&&&all&&&Anhang 41&&&52&&&all&&&Anhang 42&&&53
```

But, for some reason, the only string in group 2 is:

```
&&&Anhang 42&&&53
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: A character class always matches a single letter. No matter how often you repeat the `&` inside, or even try to group it - the `(` and `)` are just interpreted as normal characters.

Comment: Please post your input and complete regex in your question, not just a link to an external resource.

Comment: Maybe [this one](https://regex101.com/r/6Sc3aM/3) will help.

Comment: @Bergi  Then how can I negate three consecutive &'s?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  That is helpful, but I need to leave open the possibility of a single `&` being somewhere in the separated groupings.  If I insert an `&` between `Anhang` and `42`, for example, it breaks the rest.

Comment: @DavidJ. Use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to negate a pattern.

Comment: Then maybe [this one](https://regex101.com/r/6Sc3aM/4)? @Bergi: I doubt a lookahead is a good idea in such a scenario. It is just not necessary when a negated character class does all what is needed. It can be used, but it will make the pattern very resource-consuming and inefficient.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I haven't really understood what the OP needs, but to match 3 arbitrary characters that should not be 3 `&` signs in a row (but fewer are allowed) you'd use negative lookaround.

Comment: @Bergi: I understand you speak about `(?:(?!&&&)[\s\S])*` tempered greedy token, but it is very inefficient, and in the current scenario, when the string is so long, it will most probably lead to performance issues. In such cases, it is much better to unroll the token. It can be easily unrolled as `[^&]*(?:&&?[^&]+)*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Those both seem to have linear complexity? But no, I was only thinking about the non-repeating `(?!&&&)...`

Comment: @Bergi: The performance difference is huge: the tempered greedy token checks each location in the string on its way, while the unrolled pattern grabs whole chunks of text up to the specific chars, and is thus much faster. See [this link](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop).

Answer (score 0):

You get `&&&all&&&Anhang 42&&&53` in Group 2 because the `(pattern)+` is a [repeated capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) that stores only the value captured at the last iteration.

It seems you need

```
/Artikelnummer&&&([\s\S]*?)&&&Dokumentation&&&KKS-Nummer&&&Beschreibung&&&Seite((?:(?:&&&[^&]*(?:&&?[^&]+)*){2}&&&\d+)+)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Sc3aM/6)

The first capturing group just matches any 0+ chars from `Artikelnummer&&&` till the first occurrence of `&&&Dokumentation...`, and the second one grabs 1+ occurrences of `&&&...&&&...&&&` + digit(s).

**Details**

- `Artikelnummer&&&` - a literal substring
- `([\s\S]*?)`  - Group 1 matching any 0+ chars, as few as possible up to the
- `&&&Dokumentation&&&KKS-Nummer&&&Beschreibung&&&Seite` - literal substring
- `((?:&&&[^&]*(?:&&?[^&]+)*&&&[^&]*(?:&&?[^&]+)*&&&\d+)+)` - Group 2 matching 1+ occurrences of:

  - `(?:&&&[^&]*(?:&&?[^&]+)*){2}` - two occurrences of:

    - `&&&` - a literal substring
    - `[^&]*(?:&&?[^&]+)*` - any 0+ chars other than `&` and then 0+ sequences of `&` or `&&` followed with any 0+ chars other than `&`
  - `&&&`  - a literal substring
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits.

Notes on performance: the first capturing group pattern needs to be precised if you need better performance. Right now, the lazy dot pattern is too slow and if the substring between the first and second delimiter grows, then there might be performance issues.

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/6Sc3aM/7 will perform better. Still, the first group pattern is not very clear.